# (swift) Binary Operator '+' Cannot be applied to two 'Bool' Operands

Tags: swift, boolean

I'm new to programming and I'm trying swift out. But this simple code doesn't work because two bool operands can't be combined. Can someone solve the issue with this?

```
var money = true
var debt = true

if money {
var money = 500
} else {
var money = 0
}

if debt {
var debt = -10
} else {
var debt = 0
}

var totalMoney = debt + money

print (totalMoney)
```

Comment: Why do you set initial value to true? Set it to 0

Comment: How do you plan to add booleans together? True + true = ?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot sum (`+`) to 2 booleans.

What should this line mean?

```
true + false
```

You have other operators available for booleans like OR `||` or AND `&&`

### More

I suspect you want to sum the variables you are defining **inside** the scope of your IF/ELSE blocks

```
if money {
    var money = 500 // <- this
} else {
    var money = 0 // <- and this right?
}
```

But those variable only exists within the `{ }` where they are declared in.

So I suggest to use a different name for your money and debt boolean values and to define money and debt (the Int variables /constants) outside of the scope of your if

```
var isMoney = true
var isDebt = true

let money: Int
let debt: Int

if isMoney {
    money = 500
} else {
    money = 0
}

if isDebt {
    debt = -10
} else {
    debt = 0
}

var totalMoney = debt + money
```

Test

```
print(totalMoney)
// 490
```

Now you can sum `debt` and `money` because they are `Int` values